# create a file and upload the chunks to the in team drive from C#

Tags: c#

I Have to Upload the file to my teamdrive, the file has been created to team drive but I can not upload the file chunks to it. So, please help to solve it.

On Writing a Chunk I am facing the Error of "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

I am getting the Teamdrive ID and the File ID which has been created.

```
    /***       Creation of a File to Team Drive        ***/

      f_ObjFile.TeamDriveId = "/*TeamDrive ID*/";
      try
      {
          f_ObjNewFile.Parents            = f_ObjFile.Parents;   // f_ObjFile = <Team Driv ID>
          f_ObjNewFile.Name               = f_ObjFile.Name;
          f_ObjNewFile.MimeType           = f_ObjFile.MimeType;
          f_ObjNewFile.TeamDriveId        = f_ObjFile.TeamDriveId;

          f_CreateRequest = GoogleHelper.InvokeApiCall(() => { return this.DriveServiceObj.Files.Create(f_ObjNewFile); }, this);

          if (f_CreateRequest != null)
          { 
               f_CreateRequest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
               f_CreateRequest.Fields = "*";

               f_ObjNewFile = GoogleHelper.InvokeApiCall(() => { return f_CreateRequest.Execute(); }, this);
          }

          f_ObjDocumentItem = new DocumentItem(UserEmailID, f_ObjNewFile);
          f_ObjDocumentItem.ItemID = f_ObjNewFile.Id;
          string f_Url = GoogleHelper.CreateChunkURL("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/{0}?uploadType=resumable", f_ObjNewFile.Id);
          f_ObjDocumentItem.ChunkUploadURL = InitiateResumeRequest(f_Url, f_ObjNewFile.Id);

      }
      catch(Exception ex) { }

      finally
      {
          f_ObjNewFile                = null;
          f_CreateRequest             = null;
      }
```

---

### /***    Writing the chunks to the file in TeamDrive    ***/

```
      try
      {
           httpRequest                 = GoogleHelper.CreateHttpWebRequestObj(f_ObjChunkData.ChunkUploadURL,true);
           httpRequest.Method          = GoogleConstant.PATCH;

           httpRequest.ContentLength   = f_ObjChunkData.FileData.Length;
           httpRequest.SendChunked     = true;

           httpRequest.Headers["Content-Range"] = "bytes " + f_ObjChunkData.StartOffset +
                                                            "-" +
                                                            f_ObjChunkData.EndOffset + "/" +
                                                            f_ObjChunkData.FileSize.ToString();

           using (System.IO.Stream f_ObjHttpStream = GoogleHelper.InvokeApiCall(() => { return httpRequest.GetRequestStream(); }, this))
           {
               if (f_ObjHttpStream != null)
               {
                   System.IO.MemoryStream  f_ChunkStream       = null;
                   f_ChunkStream                               = new System.IO.MemoryStream(f_ObjChunkData.FileData);
                   f_ChunkStream.CopyTo(f_ObjHttpStream);
                   f_ObjHttpStream.Flush();
                   f_ObjHttpStream.Close();
                   f_ChunkStream.Close();
                   f_ChunkStream                               = null;
                }
           }

           using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = GoogleHelper.InvokeApiCall(() => { return (HttpWebResponse)(httpRequest.GetResponse()); }, this))
           {
                if (httpResponse != null)
                {
                    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        httpResponse.Close();
                    }
                }
           }

      }
      catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In Followin Line :***
`string f_Url = GoogleHelper.CreateChunkURL("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/{0}?uploadType=resumable", f_ObjNewFile.Id);`

**Insted Of**

> "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/{0}?uploadType=resumable"

**Use following URL :**

> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/{0}?uploadType=resumable&supportsTeamDrives=true

---

and its Done...
Now you can upload the chunks...